# Update large datasets in apigee baas

Tags: apigee

I have a scenario where a collection in the BaaS will have to be updated frequently. As I understand, to insert entities into a collection, I can do single HTTP POST requests with the payload containing an array of entities.

However, using HTTP PUT, I have to insert a single entity per request and I'm not sure about its performance.

What is the best / recommended way of updating a collection with a large number of entities?

Regards

Answer (score 0):

You can do a batch update using HTTP PUT.  See here: http://apigee.com/docs/app-services/content/updating-collections.  Notice that the ql clause is Usergrid query language to restrict which items get updated.

Comment: Thanks for that. 

However, that describes how to update a group of entities with the same data. 

My scenario is around updating a group of entities with different data without a PUT per entity (which requires a lot of requests). 

I can POST to an endpoint as it creates new entities but wanted to know if I could PUT to the same endpoint using either uuid or the name attribute to identify the specific entities.

Answer (score 0):

As far as I know, that needs to be done singularly.  I apologize for any inconvenience this may cause.